# split the elements in the line, how to rejoin them with the updated value

Tags: python, regex

I have many lines in a file, I wanted to match certain patterns in the line, then write the line out to a new file with updated content where the pattern is matched. I tested with one line (included in the scripts), so I want to match the lines start with digits, if it is 1, i wanted to be replaced as 1/1, 0 replaced with 0/0, I managed to match the pattern, but when I use

```
line = ' '.join(line)
            print line
```

It blowed up the whole console, printed out hundreds of lines comprise a single character at a time in each line, could you give some hints on how to correctly join these elements and write it out in a new line correctly?

```
import re

line = "gi|393925858|gb|AGTA02071966.1|    739  .   G   A   121.2   PASS    NS=74;AN=2;DP=8448  GT:DP:GQ:EC:SG  0/1:262:99:116:R    1:32:93:32:A    0:87:42:72:R    .:0:0:0:.   .:0:0:0:.   0/1:222:99:113:R"


line = line.split()


for i in line:
    matches = re.match(r'0(:\d+:\d+:\d+:[.|\w])', i)
    if matches:

        matches = i.replace('0', '0/0')

    else:
        matches = re.match(r'1(:\d+:\d+:\d+:[.|\w])', i)
        if matches:

            matches = i.replace('1', '1/1')

    line = ' '.join(line)

    print line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `line = ' '.join(line)` inside the for loop that runs over line parts. So the line splits into 15 parts, and you are rejoining and printing it 15 times.

I think the way you are naming things is making it less clear what's happening, you have several places where you overwrite one variable with something completely different, or don't use the result from something you did.

I've rewritten it a bit to make it clearer that it's splitting the line into parts, going through the parts, and either storing the part unchanged or changed, then afterwards building the output.

Try:

```
import re

line_in = "gi|393925858|gb|AGTA02071966.1|    739  .   G   A   121.2   PASS    NS=74;AN=2;DP=8448  GT:DP:GQ:EC:SG  0/1:262:99:116:R    1:32:93:32:A    0:87:42:72:R    .:0:0:0:.   .:0:0:0:.   0/1:222:99:113:R"

line_parts = line_in.split()
output_parts = []

for part in line_parts:

    output_part = part
    matches = re.match(r'0(:\d+:\d+:\d+:[.|\w])', part)

    if matches:
        output_part = part.replace('0', '0/0')

    else:
        matches = re.match(r'1(:\d+:\d+:\d+:[.|\w])', part)
        if matches:
            output_part = part.replace('1', '1/1')

    output_parts.append(output_part)

line_out = ' '.join(output_parts)
print line_out
```

NB. The lines originally have four spaces between the parts, you are rejoining them with one space, if that matters. (I suspect the are originally tab separated fields, not four spaces, and might be better read with the `csv` module unless you're sure there's never any spaces in the data itself).

**EDIT**

I think it would be even clearer with a bit of tweaking:

- The regular expression pattern is repeated. Give it a variable with a name that describes what it's looking for. I called it `thing_pattern` because I don't know what concept `1:32:93:32:A` represents.
- You don't use the 'matches' variable, so you don't really need to store it
- One part isn't going to match both 1... and 0...

So how about:

```
import re

line_in = "gi|393925858|gb|AGTA02071966.1|    739  .   G   A   121.2   PASS    NS=74;AN=2;DP=8448  GT:DP:GQ:EC:SG  0/1:262:99:116:R    1:32:93:32:A    0:87:42:72:R    .:0:0:0:.   .:0:0:0:.   0/1:222:99:113:R"

thing_pattern = r'(:\d+:\d+:\d+:[.|\w])'
line_parts = line_in.split()

output_parts = []

for part in line_parts:

    output_part = part

    if re.match('0'+thing_pattern, part):
        output_part = part.replace('0', '0/0')

    elif re.match('1'+thing_pattern, part):
        output_part = part.replace('1', '1/1')

    output_parts.append(output_part)

line_out = ' '.join(output_parts)
print line_out
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your code is way easier to understand

Comment: @user2489612 Cool. If you're interested I've edited my answer with another version at the end which is slightly rewritten, and I think it looks a bit more orderly again.

Comment: I love the way you match the pattern, this is totally awesome！

Comment: I just found that some other data also mismatched, do you know why? for example, some 0s in the middle of the pattern also mistakenly replaced "0/0:70/0:99:0/0:C 0/0:237:99:0/0:C 0/0:158:99:0/0:C 0/0:84:99:0/0:C 0/0:14:69:0/0:C 0/0:20/08:99:0/0:C"

Comment: @user2489612 ooh, yes that's a problem. The lines `part.replace(...)` are replacing *all* the zeros and *all* the ones they can find. Try making them `output_part = part.replace('0', '0/0', 1)` (adding `,1` at the end makes it only do 1 replacement, and then stop). Do that to the other line which replaces 1's as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the intermediate results in another list, finally you can join that temporary list to get the result, like this

```
line, temp = line.split(), []
for i in line:
    matches = re.match(r'0(:\d+:\d+:\d+:[.|\w])', i)
    if matches:
        matches = i.replace('0', '0/0')
    else:
        matches = re.match(r'1(:\d+:\d+:\d+:[.|\w])', i)
        if matches:
            matches = i.replace('1', '1/1')
        else:
            matches = i
    temp.append(matches)
line = ' '.join(temp)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was not aware "matches = i" and the fact that i have to set a temp space. Shameless learning by posting :) thanks